# Parse a substring from ComboBox selection

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a ComboBox "Liste_cible" with values like: BOCAL SAP-A246, or PAP-SAP-K207.

I would like to use only the last number, after the "-" (A246 or K207) to run another subroutine.

I'm looking for the function like `SUBTSTR(Me.Liste_cible.Value,”-“,-1)`

```
Private Sub liste_cible_Change()
Dim argString As String
If Not Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Liste_cible.MatchFound And Worksheets("1 - 
 Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Liste_cible <> "" Then
  MsgBox "Saisie impossible, ce partenaire cible n'existe pas !", , "Contrôle"
  Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Liste_cible = ""
 Else
  Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Cells(5, 17) = Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi    
  Commercial").Liste_cible
  MsgBox Me.Liste_cible.Value
  argString = SUBTSTR(Me.Liste_cible.Value,”-“,-1)  ??
  GET_GROUPE_GESTION_CIBLE (argString)
  INFO_PROTO1 (argString)
  INFO_PROTO2 (argString)
  End If
  End Sub
```

MsgBox Me.Liste_cible.Value works correctly, but I don't know how to get the argString.

Comment: Look at `Split`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
argString = Mid(Me.Liste_cible.Value, InStrRev(Me.Liste_cible.Value,"-") + 1)
```

Comment: thank you, how can I insert this vaule to G18, for example, because  Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("G18") = argString.Value doesn't work

Comment: I guess this should work: Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi Commercial").Range("G18").Value = argString

Comment: Thank you, it works. Do you think this formula works if I have the value like SPP-AP-SPP-K-A3444 (I mean the 4 "-" ?)

Comment: Yes, it will return the part after the last dash, A3444 is that example.

Comment: thank you Alex, could you explain please how this formula works, sorry I can't find it on Internet :) Thank you very much !

Comment: InStrRev(Me.Liste_cible.Value,"-") returns the index of the last occurence of a dash in the string, you need to add 1 because you don't need the index of the dash but the index of the next character. Mid(Me.Liste_cible.Value, index) will return the part of the string starting from the index. See also: [Mid](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_mid.asp) and [InStrRev](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_instrrev.asp).